# unity C# run method from another class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to run metod in the class from another class and both of them atached to different obj

Two classes. the first is:

```
public class NewScore: MonoBehaviour {
public void updateScoreBy( int intr) {
    Debug.Log("intr+4"+intr+4);
}
}
```

and the second is:

```
public class NewPlus: MonoBehaviour {
    public NewScore newscore;
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D obj) {
    newscore.updateScoreBy(+1);
}
}
```

When I run my code I recive an arror "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" and it points on newscore.updateScoreBy(+1);
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on what you want to do you could make the function static like:

```
public static void updateScoreBy(int intr)
{
    Debug.Log("intr+4"+intr+4);
}
```

and call it with:

```
NewScore.updateScoreBy(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `public NewScore newscore;`: drag drop the object that contains that script on that variable in the Inspector panel

Comment: It doesn't drop on the place in inspector.

Comment: if you have one gameobject with `NewScore` and another with `NewPlus` you should be able to drag one object to another, on Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize newscore.

Change your NewPlus class like this so it will initialize newscore on construction.

```
public class NewPlus: MonoBehaviour {
  public NewScore newscore;
  public NewPlus(){
    newscore=NewScore();
  }
  public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D obj) {
    newscore.updateScoreBy(+1);
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to do the same? doest'n work- shows an error on your fix

Comment: I don't know all the classes you are using. Does `NewScore` have a constructor with no arguments? If not, you are the one to know how to initialize it. I'm just telling you that you should initialize it in your constructor.